# How to design the header of a website in GWT without using CSS?

Tags: gwt

I need to make the header and logo (google Code  and Stockwatcher) of the stockwatcher example http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/gettingstarted.html without using CSS or HTML, that is all the code should be in JAVA. Can someone tell me how to do it ?

Comment: I am actually looking for the styling part, how to set font, fontsize font color without using CSS.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? manipulating styles with scripts is one of the worst things you can do wrt performance (and you'd actually use CSS anyway, just not with a "CSS stylesheet")

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create Panels and place elements in them progmatatically without a problem. But if you add more details to your questions I am sure we can be more helpful.

Also, you are linking to an older version of GWT, you might be helped by using the most recent version:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide.html

This is probably the section you are looking for:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html

But I would recommend using UiBinder where you can, instead of pure Java. It is easier and more flexible that way.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html

Comment: I am actually looking for the styling part, how to set font, fontsize font color without using CSS. If there is any way you are aware of doing this plz let me know.